# Calling a template method from another template method in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently having an issue with templated methods. I have this public class implementing a template method:

```
namespace Private { class InternalClass; }

namespace Public
{
    class PublicClass
    {
    public:
        PublicClass();
        virtual ~PublicClass();

        template<class T>
        bool Add(bool primary);

    private:
        Private::InternalClass* _pInternal;
    };

    template<class T>
    bool PublicClass::Add(bool primary) { return _pInternal->Add<T>(primary); }
}
```

The internal class is implemented that way:

```
namespace Private
{
    class InternalClass
    {
    public:
        InternalClass();
        virtual ~InternalClass();

        template <class T>
        bool Add(bool primary);
    };

    template<class T>
    bool InternalClass::Add(bool primary) { return false; }
}
```

As this internal class header won't be available with the provided sources, I must class forward it within the PublicClass header and I add the include to PrivateClass.h inside the PublicClass.cpp file.

1) Any idea why I would be getting the following error:

> error : member access into incomplete type 'Private::InternalClass' / note: forward >declaration of 'Private::InternalClass'

2) What would be the best way of hiding my PublicClass::Add() implementation?

**UPDATED**

Reason for error at 1) is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493884/calling-a-template-method-from-another-template-method-in-c?noredirect=1#comment39793168_25493884) as stated by Cornstalks.

For 2), how can I hide my implementation without including PrivateClass.h within the PublicClass header file?

Comment: Do you know what types your template will be specialized with ?

Comment: Yes, I have a bunch of classes deriving from an ITypeClass, i.e. AClass, BClass, CClass... I am calling Add<BClass>(true) or Add<CClass>(false). I don't know how many derived classes there is.

Comment: You can define the function under the `Private` definition.

Comment: @DaleWilson: I'm pretty sure there is no need to define the class as template to use template methods...

Comment: You can forward declare things, but you can't *use* objects of forward declared types (that is, you can't dereference them or call their member functions). The compiler tells you: you're accessing a member of an incomplete type (you can't call `Add` on `_pInternal`, because the "real" type of `_pInternal` isn't known, so the compiler doesn't even know `_pInternal` has an `Add` method, nor how to call such a member).

Comment: Never (Except in some specific cases like `std::forward` or `std::make_shared`) use hardcoded template parameters instead of template deduction

Comment: @Cornstalks, great thanks for the info! Do you see any way of fixing the problem I am having?

Comment: @Manu343726: The OP isn't able to use template deduction, as the function argument is just a `bool`, not a `T`. The template parameter *must* be specified.

Comment: In what way do you want to hide hide your `PublicClass::Add` method? Also, can't you just put the implementation of `PublicClass::Add` in a separate `Public` namespace block after the `Private` namespace block or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What do you need to do in `InternalClass::Add`? What information do you need from the template argument type `T`? E.g. can you replace the template argument by a `type_info` function parameter? Can you use type erasure instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have encountered a very interesting problem - you want to implement the **[PImpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)** where the privately implemented class has a template method. Well, this can be solved, meaning you CAN hide the template's implementation, but only **when you know** which types will be used to instantiate your `Add<T>` method in your program.

Say, your template will work only with types `AClass` and `BClass`. Then you can split your files as follows (comments are inlined):

**File public.h**:

```
#ifndef PUBLIC_H
#define PUBLIC_H

// Forward declaration ! It's sufficient in this case !
namespace Private { class InternalClass; }

// Declare all classes your Add<T> method should work with
struct AClass {};
struct BClass {};

namespace Public
{
    class PublicClass
    {
    public:
        PublicClass() {}
        virtual ~PublicClass() {}

        template <typename T>
        bool Add(bool primary); // DO NOT implement this method, just declare

    private:
        Private::InternalClass* _pInternal;
    };

    // "Explicit instantiation declarations", for each type the method will work with:
    extern template bool PublicClass::Add<AClass>(bool primary);

    extern template bool PublicClass::Add<BClass>(bool primary);
}

#endif
```

**File public.cpp**:

```
#include "public.h"

// NOTE: this is hidden in CPP file, noone will see your implementation
namespace Private
{
    class InternalClass
    {
    public:
        InternalClass() {}
        virtual ~InternalClass() {}

        template <typename T>
        bool Add(bool primary);
    };

    // Magic! Here is the actual implementation of your private method
    template <typename T>
    bool InternalClass::Add(bool primary)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

namespace Public
{
    // Original definition moved to CPP file !
    template <typename T>
    bool PublicClass::Add(bool primary)
    {
        return _pInternal->Add<T>(primary);
    }

    // And again list the allowed types, this time using "explicit instantiation definitions"
    template bool PublicClass::Add<AClass>(bool primary);

    template bool PublicClass::Add<BClass>(bool primary);
}
```

**File main.cpp**:

```
#include "public.h"

int main()
{
    Public::PublicClass pc;
    pc.Add<AClass>(true); // works !
    pc.Add<BClass>(false); // works !

    // pc.Add<int>(true); linker error as expected,
    // becuase there is no explicit instantiation for Add<int>

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Piotr! I was able to implement properly the changes. It is working great!